# What does the term Principal mean in .NET Security?

Tags: asp.net

I'm reading this article
http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/.NET/net_security/authentication/article.php/c7415/

I still don't understand the concept of "Principal" (why this name) what's difference with just Identity in common language ?

For example in the tutorial I don't understand the distinction between UserIdentity and SecurityPrincipal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term principal comes from the theoretical-side of computer security. It is simply used to refer to an entity that can be identified through some mechanism of authentication. I wouldn't worry about it to be honest.

Take a look at these artcles -- they may help clear things up.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780957(WS.10).aspx
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_principal
 http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/What%20Is%20A%20Security%20Principal.html

Comment: Well I worried because I don't understand the distinction between UserIdentity and SecurityPrincipal ?